# change pointed instance inside a function in python

Tags: python

i'm newer in python but i have some package from other languages . Here's my question :
i need to change an instance reference inside a function.This instance is passed as parameter.
but i didn't know how to do it. I think i miss something in Python basics.The code bellow is given as example for what i want:

```
class Foo(object): 
   def __init__(self,a):
      self.a = a


def func(a):
   b = Foo(3)
   a = b

var1 = Foo(5)
print(var1.a) # 5
func(var1)
print(var1.a) # it display 5 not 3
```

Comment: You mean you want a [copy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) of the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use an umutable object such as the list and the property functions that automagically does what you need.

```
class Foo(object): 
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._a = [value]

    def __geta(self):
        return self._a[0]

    def __seta(self, obj):
        self._a.insert(0, obj)
        self._a.pop(1)

    a = property(__geta, __seta)

var1 = Foo(5)
print var1.a
var1.a = 3
print(var1.a)
```

Comment: i thought to do such at first, but it still doesn't work. the probleme is when you back from the function the object is the same.(the modication should be inside a function)

Answer (score 1):

You can make `func` return `a` and then assign that to `var1` as follows:

```
def func(a):
   b = Foo(3)
   a = b
   return a

var1 = Foo(5)
print(var1.a) # 5
var1 = func(var1)
print(var1.a) # 3

>>> var1.a
3
```

What you were doing in your code is that you were changing the pointer for the `local` variable `a` in your `func(a)` method. However, if you want to change the `var1` pointer, you have to assign the changed `a` variable that you passed as an argument.

Comment: first,thank you for reply. But it's not what i want.may be because i didn't mention that the function shouldn't return. it's an implementation that i should respect.